# Send selected item to database from a spinner

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to send the selected item from the spinner to database. what should be the type of a spinner:

```
type = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.type);
```

this statement is not working

Comment: Frame your question properly and show in the code how your are fetching spinner data and inserting it into database.

Answer (score 0):

it should be declared like and no need to do explicit casting:

```
Spinner type = findViewById(R.id.type);
```

and selected type can be get in

```
type.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
      @Override
         public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

       }

      @Override
         public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
         }

});
```